# Problem implementing JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

```
DefaultPieDataset myColoredPieChart = new DefaultPieDataset();                
     myColoredPieChart.setValue("Java", 12.9);    
     .......
     org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart myColoredChart=ChartFactory.createPieChart("Programming - Colored Pie Chart Example",myColoredPieChart,true,true,false);
```

I get a error "The type org.jfree.util.PublicCloneable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Anyone a idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JFreeChart is packaged as multiple jar files; you're probably not including all of them in your program. The one named `jcommon-XXX.jar` contains the class that's missing, so be sure to inclide that one in your program.

Comment: In fact I did miss that jar but it doesn't solve the problem ... I have a problem with this import now : import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;    and a error message : The import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Comment: Problem with jcommon .. downloaded another and added it to my buildpath and problem solved.

Comment: I did not include jcommon jar in the build path. Thank you for helping!